# What determines which bracket is shown in your profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, reputation-leagues

There's a fancy new link in your profile page that shows when you're in the top X% of some bracket - week, month, quarter, year, and all time. Though, I haven't seen week and year myself.

What determines which bracket you're in, though? I originally figured it would be the highest bracket, but the [#1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/102/tzenes) and [#3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/122/oak) users on Gaming are shown as `top 1% overall`, while [player 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer) only is shown as `top 1% this quarter`.

It's not whichever bracket you are highest ranked in, either (as player 2 happens to be the #1 for this quarter). [Fabian](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4103/fabian) is listed as `top #1 this quarter`, but his quarter rank is 4th, which is less than his month rank of 3rd.

Comment: I thought it was your best stat too, but that was only through checking my profiles.

Comment: Top X% this week: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4393/resorath; as regards top this year, keep in mind that right now quarter == year.

Comment: I really don't understand how that works, on gaming I'm in the top 1% of the quarter while I'm easily in the top 1% overall, on skeptics I'm in the top 6% of the month (the site exists for 5 days) while being #1 with 300 rep lead on the next user.

Comment: @Fabian I've noticed that for all of the Stack Exchange sites created in 2011, they don't show any brackets larger than the month.

Comment: Well, the reputation leagues on skeptics still return a 404, I don't think the whole thing is designed for sites that just barely started

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a somewhat related investigation here.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81255/156011

From a black box observation, it is clearly the BEST % (*percentage*).  Dissecting only one case

> Fabian is listed as top #1 this quarter, but his quarter rank is 4th, which is less than his month rank of 3rd.

- month rank #3. Last page of ranking has user #116, so he's 3/116.
- quarter rank #4. Last page of ranking is up to user #514, so it's 4/514.

Clearly the 4/514 ranks higher, without calculating the decimals.

Okay I'll bite and take another case.  [raven-dreamer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer) is #1 this quarter, and #2 overall. Without going into details, the #1/(users ranked in qtr) > #2/(all users).